# Advantage of using SideWaffle to create templates compared to writing a VSIX

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, sidewaffle

I understand that SideWaffle provides a bunch of community-driven templates for web developers.

What I don't get is whether there is an advantage to using SideWaffle for writing my own templates for corporate use.  The instructions provided, eg:

- https://github.com/ligershark/side-waffle/wiki/How-SideWaffle-Works
- https://github.com/ligershark/side-waffle/wiki/How-to-create-a-project-template
- https://github.com/ligershark/side-waffle/wiki/How-to-create-a-multi-project-template

don't seem any easier than just writing a VSIX package (eg http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308.aspx ).

Am I missing something?  As a template author, what does SideWaffle do for me?

Comment: How are you creating templates today?

Comment: I don't have much experience creating templates, but I was thinking I'd creating a VSIX containing several templates, including a multi-project template.  Does using SideWaffle make that any easier/better?

Comment: Try it without SideWaffle/TemplateBuilder and then get back to me. I don't even know how you would start unless you were very knowledgeable of the subject, theres a lot of moving parts, and ways to go wrong. The video to watch is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z33jOo75CH4&list=UUwEinBp3Mx1UuAR52pzRcNw

Comment: FYI for multi project templates you should use a custom wizard to appropriately handle the name passed in. You can use wizards already available in TemplateBuilder (SideWaffle is built on TB). Here is multi proj doc https://github.com/ligershark/side-waffle/wiki/How-to-create-a-multi-project-template. Multi prom templates are still tough even w TB, without TB its nuts.